# Intellij idea usb device debugging app doesn't load on phone

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I have a nexus 4 and all the required drivers installed (the phone is recognized with the "adb devices" command).

When I try to debug my android app with Intellij idea over USB I get this output:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_4-xxxxxxxx
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Java Projects\Test GDX Project\android\build\apk\android-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.testgdx.game.android
```

But nothing ever loads on my phone?

**EDIT: After I manually installed the app once, usb device debugging started to work all of a sudden.**

Comment: please post Manifest plus please rebuild and clean your project

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6t4Gz4gU

I've tried both and there is no difference

Comment: silly question have u enable Debugging mode on your Nexus 4? plus is not debug mode working usual?

Comment: Yes I have enabled it, I don't really know what you mean by working as usual. Everything looks as it should and Intellij Idea acts as if everything is as it should. Only problem is that the app never opens on the phone itself :/

Comment: If I manually loads the apk to the phone the app installs and starts without any troubles...

Answer (score 1):

Trying using a different USB cable (i.e. original cable and not a cheap 0.99$ cable). for some devices, some cables are not compatible for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 7**

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for the first time:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Devices in the left pane.

Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.

Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.

Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.

Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)

Click Next to install the driver.